# Certain keyboard shortcuts do not work on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

So I just got a new mechanical keyboard and plugged it in, and found out that my ctrl+1, ctrl+2, and ctrl+3 keys do not work.

I switched back to my old keyboard and they do not work.

I tried to teamviewer in with a different computer, and that did not work.

I tested this key combination on Chrome, Firefox, and in World of Warcraft, and it no longer works. Is there any solution to this? Thanks!

Edit: Also wanted to say that ctrl+4 works and I'm able to switch to the fourth tab, but not the first three.

Comment: I guess you checked out http://superuser.com/questions/223941/ctrl-1-and-ctrl-2-key-combinations-dont-work ? Though they didn't really find any good solutions, yesterday someone posted "uninstalling Geforce experience gave me my CRTL+1-3 keys back."

Comment: OH! I wonder! Because just two days ago, I updated my geforce experience drivers. I'll check that out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There was a new update for the geforce drivers and it fixed it!